# Jquery recursive update element class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need a function for update class of div. i want the rank increase by 1 on each node. Better use this exemple for explain my needs :

i have some div as follow :

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="1" class="rank2">
    <div id="2" class="rank4">
      <div id="3" class="rank7">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="rank4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="rank2">
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="rank2">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like a function to update every rank like this :

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="1" class="rank1">
    <div id="2" class="rank2">
      <div id="3" class="rank3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="rank2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="rank1">
  </div>
  <div id="5" class="rank1">
  </div>
</div>
```

So every nested div have a rank increase by one.

My try by far :

```
var rank = 1;

function initRank() {
  $.each($("#content").find($(".rank"+rank)), function() {
    if (rank >= 2 && $(this).parents(".rank"+(rank-1).length <= 0 )) {
      $(this).removeClass("rank"+rank).addClass("rank"+(rank-1));
      rank--;
      initRank();
    }
  })
  rank++;
  if (rank < 10) {
    initRank();
  } else {
    return; 
  }
}
```

And [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qo8s7xzy/)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't afraid of recursion, here's a modified version of your demo :
https://jsfiddle.net/qo8s7xzy/3/

I used regexp to check existing classes, you'll have to improve it if you want to use double digit ranks

```
.replace(/rank\d/g, "rank"+rank)
```

It'll work with other elements in-between divs, that may or may not be what you want.